# I use TransitionDrawable to change background color but it occure error - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I use following java code to run this,

```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int transitionTime = 300;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutMain).getBackground();
    transition.startTransition(transitionTime);

}
```

[image]

Please help me to sole this problem.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: thanks SimY4 I done this using different way.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm new to android and what I'm try to do is change layout background color continuously.

Above method trigger error to me, I not found solution to this but I use different approach to do this.

I use timer with TransitionDrawable and here is my working copy of code.

Here I add "drawable" resources,

transition_drawable.xml (this is main resource xml set this resource file to your layer backbround)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_selector_01" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_selector_02" />
</transition>
```

color_selector_01.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>
     <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#919bfa"
        android:endColor="#4e5bda"
        android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

color_selector_02.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
      <shape>
         <gradient
           android:angle="90"
           android:startColor="#fe5528"
           android:endColor="#3c1ed4"
           android:type="linear" />
     </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

In my main layout I set layer background to "transition_drawable"

here is my "activity_main.xml"

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@drawable/transition_drawable" >

 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/linkTerms"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/linkTerms" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/and"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/and" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/linkPrivacy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/linkPrivacy" />
        </LinearLayout>

     </ScrollView>
```

Finlay here is my MainActivity.java file

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int transitionTime = 6000;


    private RelativeLayout Rlayout;
    private TransitionDrawable trans;

    final Handler handler_interact=new Handler();//not defined as final variable. may cause        problem
    View layout_interact;


@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    layout_interact =(View) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutMain);

    Rlayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutMain);
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    trans = (TransitionDrawable)res.getDrawable(R.drawable.transition_drawable);

    Rlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);

    BackgroundColoerChangerCallTimer();


}



public void BackgroundColoerChangerCallTimer(){
     //creating timer
    Timer timer_interact=new Timer();
    timer_interact.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            UpdateGUI();
            }
    }, 3000);
}



private void UpdateGUI() {
    handler_interact.post(runnable_interact);
}


//creating runnable
final Runnable runnable_interact = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //ayout_interact.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        trans.reverseTransition(transitionTime);
        BackgroundColoerChangerCallTimer();
    }
};
```